# How can I force-cast a data to the generics specified in the method constraint?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following data class and VM class:

```
public interface IData
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
    }
   }

public class DataPartial: IData
{

    public DataPartial()
    {


    }

    public string Name => "Data partial";
}

public class DataFull : IData
{
    public string Name => "Data full";

    public DataFull()
    {

    }
}

public interface IVM
{
    IData Data { get; }
}
public interface IVM_partial: IVM
{
  new  DataPartial Data { get; }
}


public class VM_Partial : IVM_partial
{
    public VM_Partial()
    {
        Data = new DataPartial();

    }
    public DataPartial Data { get; set; }

    IData IVM.Data => Data;
}
public interface IVM_Total:IVM_partial
{
   new DataFull Data { get; }
}



public class VM_Total : IVM_Total
{


    public VM_Total(IVM_partial dataA)
    {
        Data = new DataFull();
        DataA_interface = dataA;
    }

    public IVM_partial DataA_interface { get; }


    public DataFull Data { get; private set; }

    DataPartial IVM_partial.Data => DataA_interface.Data;

    IData IVM.Data => Data;
}

public static class RunVM<T, VM>
    where T: class, IData
    where VM :class, IVM
{
    public static T RunMe(VM hi)
    {
        var vmA = (hi as VM);  //how to force-cast this to the VM type??!!
        return (T)vmA.Data; 
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VM_Partial partialData = new VM_Partial();

        var VMClass = new VM_Total(partialData);


        RunVM<DataFull, IVM_Total>.RunMe(VMClass);
        RunVM<DataPartial, IVM_partial>.RunMe(VMClass); //here it throws exception because I can't force cast the IVM to IVM_partial

    }



}
```

At the method  `RunVM<DataPartial, IVM_partial>.RunMe(VMClass);`, I want it to return me the `DataPartial` object, which I know it's there in the object `VMClass`, but I cannot get it done.

I will get an `InvalidCastException` when I am at the `RunMe` method, because the parameter `hi` is always `VMClass`, and I can never get it to behave like `IVM_partial` class. In other words, I can't cast `hi` to a more basic interface `IVM_partial`.

How to cast `hi` to a more basic interface `IVM_partial`? Is it possible at all, and if not, why not?

Comment: if you want to return an IData and your constraint is an IData, why not just make it implicit public static IData RunMe(VM hi)

Comment: There seems to be a serious abuse of spagettification here and its extremely hard to see why you want to force DataFull into DataPartial or what you want to achieve considering you have access to IData

Comment: @Saruman this is an oversimplification of my usage and I don't blame you for not seeing why I am doing this. But is it possible that you concentrate on the answer to my question instead of criticizing my design?

Comment: Not critiquing, just trying to work out what you want to achieve, note spagettification comment was just for added flavor, your welcome :)

Comment: It will not going to work like this, because method of which interface to call is determined at compile and not run time. Instead of trying to patch this code - it's indeed better to just redesign it from scratch, especially if you say that it's oversimplification and your real code is even more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the cast that's the problem - it's that you expect the compiler (or runtime) to pick up on the fact that the cast is to a type that declares a new `Data` property.

This line in `RunMe`:

```
return (T)vmA.Data;
```

... will *always* use the `Data` property declared by `IVM`, because that's the only property the compiler knows about when it's compiling that method. It doesn't matter that you're casting to another interface that contains a new `Data` property... the cast is about an execution-time check; it *doesn't* change which `Data` property the method uses.

It's unclear to me exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but I strongly suspect that you'll need to change tack significantly - maybe by adding another generic type parameter into the mix, maybe by using polymorphism more, or maybe changing the design more radically.

Comment: *maybe by adding another generic type parameter into the mix*-- is it possible to illustrate how I can do this?

Comment: @Graviton: Not without a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve, or how general it is. If you only have two notions - "full" and "partial" - then perhaps your `IVM` interface should have `FullData` and `PartialData` properties?

Comment: Jon, `IVM_Full` and `DataFull` are located at a higher assembly than `IVM`, so not possible for `IVM` to know anything about `*_Full`

Comment: @Graviton: As I said: context is important, and we don't know what you're trying to achieve. I've answered the question about why you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing, and explained that your current approach won't work - I suggest you go back to the drawing board, and if you can't work out an alternative strategy, ask a new question with more context.